# ERROR ArcPY parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 2)

Tags: arcpy, python

I'm trying to convert multiple lines to points so I typed the code bellow but it keeps on showing me this error:

> Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 2)

```
liste_ligne =["E1_H20A_H35_D21E","E1_I_H16A_H18B","E1_K_D16A_D18B","E1_L_H14_H16B","E1_H2_D70_D40C","G1_D50_D55_H40C","E1_H1_D60_D65_H70","E1_M_D12_H12","E1_Bbis_H45","E1_C_H18A","E1_C_H40","E1_D20A_D21A_D35","E1_E_D18A","E1_E_H50","E1_Bbis_D20E1","E1_G2_D21C_H60_H65","E1_LM_LoisirMoyen","E1_Bbis_D20E","E1_F2_D40_D45","E1_LL_LoisirLong","E1_ABIS_H20E_H21A","E1_F1_H55_H21C","E1_Lbis_D16B_D14"]
# loop the elements on the list
for ligne in liste_ligne: 
# link to shapefile to join
inFeatures = "E:\shapes\"+ligne+".shp"
# link to output
outFeatureClass = " E:\E1TracesPoints\+ligne
# Execute FeatureVerticesToPoints
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(inFeatures, outFeatureClass, "MID")
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: The code that you have presented seems to have an indentation error. Where are you running it from?

Answer (score 3):

You have some issues:

1. Your indentation after `for` line is incorrect.
2. Use `os.path.join` to combine path and filenames.
3. Use raw syntax for paths, for example `r'E:\somefolder'` or backslashes can cause problems.
4. You cant enclose the variable `ligne` in quotes. That will make it a string and not the variable holding your list value.

Example:

```
import arcpy, os

liste_ligne =["E1_H20A_H35_D21E","E1_I_H16A_H18B"]
shapefolder = r'E:\shapes'
outfolder = r'E:\E1TracesPoints'

for ligne in liste_ligne:
    inFeatures = os.path.join(shapefolder,ligne+'.shp')
    outFeatureClass = os.path.join(outfolder,ligne+'.shp')
    arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(inFeatures, outFeatureClass, "MID")
```

Comment: i tested the code that you proposed and it showed no ERROR but 
it hasn't gave me the results that i was expecting.
the results that i expected is multiple points that replaces the polyline, but whith your code i only get one single point.
it's odd because when i use the tool vertices to point manually it gives me the result i expect but with the code i only get one single point. 
do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: @WiemBelhadj that is what you get with `"MID"` option, remove it to get all vertices